# Filter(Array(Range)) not working for populatin User_Form Combo-Box

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make a wildcard search-as-type combobox in VB userform.
Searched target is in excel column.

I can run with:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Populate(Optional fltr As String)
    ComboBox1.List = Filter(Array("a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"), fltr)
End Sub
```

---

but failed when using:

```
Sub Combobox1_Populate(Optional fltr As String)
    ComboBox1.List = Filter(Array(Range("A1:A9")), fltr)**
End Sub
```

> Run-Time error '13'
>
> Type Mismatch

Why is `Filter(Array(Range` not working? Please help to correct it.

---

it has below too with no problem. just the `Array(Range` not work when merge with Filter

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Call Combobox1_Populate(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call Combobox1_Populate
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range` always returns a 2D array and `Filter` will only accept a 1D one. Transpose the range using `Application.Transpose`.

Comment: yup it does the job!

Comment: Thanks Rory, i didn't know that and always went with dictionaries on filter :/ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Sub Combobox1_Populate(Optional fltr As String)

    ComboBox1.List = Filter(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A9")), fltr)

End Sub

'==============================================================

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call Combobox1_Populate("shai") '<-- add the filter string in brackets, I've tested with "shai"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank You sooo much Shai.  
Now i have a "wildcard search-as-type combobox"